# Execution conditions of PDF JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf

If I use Adobe Acrobat to create a PDF that uses JavaScript, under what conditions can that JavaScript be executed?

If I display a PDF to the user inside a web browser, can the JavaScript be executed there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In German, there is a nice term "Jein" (I don't know of an English equivalent).

Primarily, the main condition that (Acrobat) JavaScript works is that the PDF viewer used has (Acrobat) JavaScript implemented (at least the Objects, Properties and Methods used in the form). There are several PDF viewers besides Acrobat/Reader which do have a decent support of JavaScript, such as Nitro, Bluebeam, Foxit, PDFExpert, qPDF, etc.).

With webbrowsers, it depends whether it is the browser's own PDF viewing component, or whether the Acrobat browser plug-in is used. In the first case, you won't have any JavaScript support. In the second case, you have.